# Rung or rang / have rung or have rang

Tags: tenses

> Have rung the sullen doorbell in vain,
> Stared at the obdurate panels, insane
> Wooden barriers and railings made of pain,
> And a mailbox to carry an epitaph.

This is a poem I've written — now, I want to take out 'Have' in the first line and just have it say 'Rung the sullen doorbell'. This is all past tense. Can I say rung or does it have to be rang?

Answer (score 1):

It's a poem: you can say what you want.

But

*Rung* is the past participle. Using *rung* there implies (to me at least) that's a poetic form of "The sullen doorbell **was rung** in vain" which then doesn't go with *stared.*